# How do you provide "context" in an "Object" or "Singleton" class in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, singleton, android-permissions

I have this warning:

> Call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should explicitly check to see if permission is available (with `checkPermission`) or explicitly handle a potential `SecurityException`

The thing is when I use what they want me to use like here with the warning:

```
  if (operation is Connect) {
            with(operation) {
                Timber.w("Connecting to ${device.name} | ${device.address}")
                device.connectGatt(context, false, gattCallback)
                isConnected.value = true
            }
            return
        }
```

And after I select the "Add Permission Check":

```
 if (operation is Connect) {
        with(operation) {
            Timber.w("Connecting to ${device.name} | ${device.address}")
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return
            }
            device.connectGatt(context, false, gattCallback)
            isConnected.value = true
        }
        return
    }
```

"this" is underlined in red as an error expecting context but found "Connect". What am I supposed to do in this situation?

[image]
EDIT: This one too
[image]

This error is in a few parts of the code, they started appearing after I updated Android Studio and Gradle. I'm not gonna lie, I'm not that experienced with Kotlin nor with singleton classes. But the class itself was based on a tutorial that used an "Object" class in the sense of it being instantiated only once, I believe that's what's called a singleton class though I am not sure if I am using it correctly.

Comment: `device.connectGatt(context, false, gattCallback)` <- Is `context` there a `Context` instance? That is, does `ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, …)` work? (Btw, might make more sense to use `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()` instead of `ActivityCompat`, but they're both the same function, ultimately.)

Comment: No I don't think have a context instance but there are some functions in the class that take context as a parameter

Comment: That was a rhetorical question, really. That is the `Context` to pass `checkSelfPermission()`.

Comment: any idea why this became an error? I mean this only popped up after updating the IDE but wasn't present before

Comment: You are casting operation to connect, then you even scoped to it with `with()`. So you are not passing context you are passing connect.

Comment: Try passing a ref to context.

Comment: You mean the "Call requires permission…" warning? You might've upgraded from a version that didn't have that lint check/inspection yet.

Comment: No, simply you are passing a reference `this` which is connect, you need to just pass `context` good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `this` which is a reference to `Connect` not `Context`. Just pass context.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Okay that one makes sense but what about the one in my edit?

Comment: You are scoped to the post, which has no return type. So `this` is nothing

Comment: https://play.kotlinlang.org/byExample/04_functional/02_Lambdas

Comment: `this` follows up to progressively higher scopes until there's a scope that's a class or function with receiver. So `this` is nothing only if this function is defined at the top level, outside a class. If it's in an `object`, then that `object` is `this`. In the OP's case, `this` is the anonymous object, which is why the ID doesn't show a name for it.

Comment: @Tenfour so in that case what is to be written instead of "this"?

Comment: You need to pass a Context instance to this function and use that. Activities and Fragments have contexts that they can pass as an argument.